# Access windows server 12 r2 adfs from host machine

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

Wanted to know if host user can access ADFS server installed on vmware. I installed and configured AD FS on windows server 2012 r2 and now I want to test AD FS sso authentication. I tried to access it through IP but it shows that site can be reached. There are network connection between my local machine and vmware and I can access IIS default web page and can ping server IP. Is there a way to access AD FS web page from user local machine. ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, can you access the metadata from your local PC?

https://hostname/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml

If you can, you can setup a SAML or WS-Fed application that runs on your PC and can access ADFS.